# What is the distribution of the number of boys standing between the leftmost girl and the rightmost girl?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions

> $10$ Boys and $10$ Girls get ordered in a line.  How is $X$, the number of boys standing between the leftmost girl and the rightmost girl, distributed?

I tried thinking of selecting one place from the $20$ for the leftmost girl, and then selecting k places from the $19$ left for the boys. Or selecting one place from the $19$ left for the rightmost girl. I can't figure how to solve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the possible number of positions between the leftmost girl and rightmost girl.

Answer (score 4):

The total number of placements is $\binom{20}{10}$. The number of placements with $n$ boys between the outermost girls is $(11-n)\binom{8+n}8$, namely $11-n$ ways for the pair of outermost girls to be placed, and $\binom{8+n}8$ ways to place the remaining $8$ girls in the places in between. So the distribution is given by those numbers for $n=0,\ldots,10$ over a common denominator of $\binom{20}{10}=184756$. The respective numerators are $$11,90,405,1320,3465,7722,15015,25740,38610,48620,43758$$
and indeed their sum is $184756$.

Comment: Why is it okay to think only about positioning the girls? Is it because for the boys we pick n places from n?

Comment: @topzeramail Once you know which positions are occupied by girls, those at the remaining positions must be boys; there is no choice (or more precisely, just one possible choice) left. I guess this glosses over the possibility of non-binary kids, but that omission is more or less enshrined in the question.

Comment: What is a "non-binary kid"?

Comment: @John_Krampf A kid that [does not identify itself with either the (pure) female or male gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-binary_gender)

Comment: Is this an American thing? I never heard of them before

Comment: @John_Krampf Whether or not you have heard of something before seems way off topic. For the record I was just commenting on whether "if a child is not a girl then it must be a boy" is logically valid; a bit like the law of the excluded middle, but not really.

Answer (score 1):

Between the *leftmost* girl and the *rightmost* girl are **always 8 girls** plus $0$ to $10$ boys.

Now:

- If there is **no boy** between them, the group of $\color{red}{10}$ girls may be in **11** different configurations:

  ```
  [GGGGGGGGGG]bbbbbbbbbb
  b[GGGGGGGGGG]bbbbbbbbb
       ...
  bbbbbbbbbb[GGGGGGGGGG]
  ```
- If there is **1 boy**, the group from the leftmost girl to the rightmost girl will have $\color{red}{11}$ members, and there are only **10** different places for the group as a whole, for example

  ```
  bb[GGGGGGbGGGG]bbbbbbb
  ```

  On the other hand, every of 10 possible locations may have that 1 boy in **9** different positions inside a group, so there are 10 × 9 = **90** possibilities.
- If there are **2 boys**, the group from the leftmost girl to the rightmost girl will have $\color{red}{12}$ members, and there are only **9** different places for the group as a whole.

  But every of 9 possible locations may have those 2 boys in $\binom{10} 2$ = **45** different positions inside a group, so there are 9 × 45 = **405** possibilities.

So the distributions of boys between the leftmost and the rightmost girl is for now:

| Boys | Occurrences |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 |  |
| 1 | 90 |  |
| 2 | 405 |  |

And you may continue ...

Comment: The boys cannot be at an outermost position in the group.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, thank you very much, you are right, I corrected my answer.